# Why aren't half of my logical partitions available?

Tags: linux, debian, partition, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to partition the eMMC on a Beaglebone Black.  Here is how I have /dev/mmcblk1 partitioned:

```
root@beaglebone:~# fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk1
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 3.6 GiB, 3825205248 bytes, 7471104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9ccd5613

Device          Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1  *       2048  206847  204800  100M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk1p2        206848 7112703 6905856  3.3G  5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk1p5        208896  823295  614400  300M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p6        825344 1849343 1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p7       1851392 2875391 1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p8       2877440 3901439 1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p9       3903488 4927487 1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p10      4929536 7026687 2097152    1G 83 Linux
```

That's exactly how it should look.  Partition 1 is a primary, partition 2 is extended, and the rest are logical.  However, when I list devices, I only see partitions 1, 2, 5, 6, and 7.

```
root@beaglebone:~# ls -l /dev/mmcblk1p*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179,  9 Mar  2 23:53 /dev/mmcblk1p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 10 Mar  2 23:53 /dev/mmcblk1p2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 13 Mar  2 23:53 /dev/mmcblk1p5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 14 Mar  2 23:53 /dev/mmcblk1p6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 15 Mar  2 23:53 /dev/mmcblk1p7
```

lsblk shows the same:

```
root@beaglebone:~# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0  7.2G  0 disk
└─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  3.3G  0 part /
mmcblk1      179:8    0  3.6G  0 disk
├─mmcblk1p1  179:9    0  100M  0 part
├─mmcblk1p2  179:10   0    1K  0 part
├─mmcblk1p5  179:13   0  300M  0 part
├─mmcblk1p6  179:14   0  500M  0 part
└─mmcblk1p7  179:15   0  500M  0 part
mmcblk1boot0 179:16   0    4M  1 disk
mmcblk1boot1 179:24   0    4M  1 disk
```

This is true even after a reboot.  I'm trying to do this booted from the SD card running debian 9 (Linux beaglebone 4.4.84-ti-r120).

Does anybody know what might be going on here?  Have I hit some sort of limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on Kernel developer seems to assume a fixed limit of four partitions for MMC.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.3/source/drivers/mmc/card/block.c#L1587

EDIT:

The question was asked already over at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/899138) and answered with help of the Beaglebone Black kernel maintainer Robert C Nelson. The answer is basically the same as [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams already posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427813/a/427814) but it's missing info about the boot argument.

Reading the source it looks like the kernel should print `mmcblk: using 16 minors per device` if the `mmcblk.perdev_minors=16` boot argument is working correctly. 
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.84/source/drivers/mmc/card/block.c#L2694

Comment: Well certainly 4 primaries are the max, but it's more complicated than that.  I've now combined 4 of my partitions in to two, which will work but isn't ideal.  That leaves me with 4 primary (with one being an extended container), and 2 logical partitions, and that seems to be working.

Comment: It looks like the question already showed up on superuser and Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is right with his answer. https://superuser.com/questions/899138

Comment: There is a way to verify if your boot argument had an effect. The kernel should post a info about `perdev_minor` being different than CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_MINORS. See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.84/source/drivers/mmc/card/block.c#L2694

Comment: Interesting.  I have no such message, so it's not taking effect.

Answer (score 3):

> The start of next SD/MMC card can be configured with CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_MINORS, or overridden at boot/modprobe time using the mmcblk.perdev_minors option. That would bump the offset between each card to be the configured value instead of the default 8.

[source](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devices.txt#2497)

So, pass `mmcblk.perdev_minors=16` on the kernel boot line.

Comment: I added that to the cmdline.  /proc/cmdline shows:

console=ttyO0,115200n8 bone_capemgr.uboot_capemgr_enabled=1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet mmcblk.perdev_minors=16

But nothing has changed.  I still see just up to /dev/mmcblk1p7.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Dave it did not help for me to pass the kernel parameter mmcblk.perdev_minors=16 (yes, my kernel was configured with CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK=y). Using the script extract-vmlinux and searching the uncompressed binary for strings it turned out that my kernel instead wanted the following parameter:

mmc_block.perdev_minors=16

Replacing mmcblk with mmc_block allowed me to see all my partitions.
I am using kernel 4.4.75, the documentation still says mmcblk instead of mmc_block in that source tree.

I found this question with its answers very useful to start debugging my problem and hope that my answer will help others with newer kernels.